# Why does Ubuntu CD contain a "pics" folder with Debian-related images?

Tags: live-cd, debian, html

There is a "pics" folder on the Ubuntu CD, containing some PNG files, which are apparently a part of an offline HTML document about Debian. Just curious, is there any use of them somewhere in the live CD/installer?

Comment: I think this is somewhat analogous to "junk" sequences in our DNA. They provide clues and information about our ancestors. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These files are part of the [debian-cd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/debian-cd) package, which is used to build the Ubuntu live CDs.

The images are sourced by an include file named `README.html.in`, which the `add-bin-doc` tool incorporates into `README.html` at the root of the CD's filesystem. This file is either never generated or is deleted from Ubuntu's CDs, so I believe the images are unused.